# Similar command to "background-position" for divs/images in CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to style a metro-like gallery. I already achieved this in an example with background-images:

http://codepen.io/DanielCoding/pen/jlrgv

But I want to replace the background-images by ordinary image-tags in divs. Unfortunately all images are stretching themselves in the bottom-right direction:

http://codepen.io/DanielCoding/pen/fsKjE/

In the first code I resolved this by give the images different background-position values, but I don't know a similar command for simple image tags or divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `transform` to scale the image and `transform-origin` to control the direction of the scale.

```
.star1:hover,
.star2:hover,
.star3:hover,
.star4:hover {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
}

.star1:hover {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom right;
}

.star2:hover {
  -webkit-transform-origin: bottom left;
}

.star3:hover {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top right;
}

.star4:hover {
  -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxsge/

Answer (score 0):

The most similar technique to "background-position" that you can use with simple images is "[**CLIP**](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)". Please, look at link in order to understand more about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced the `background-image`s with simple `img` and check this out if this is what your looking for.

```
star1,
.star2,
.star3,
.star4{
    background-size: 150px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-clip: border-box;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

.star1:hover,
.star2:hover,
.star3:hover,
.star4:hover{
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Pen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EIBuh/)

Comment: Hi and thank you. But my goal is to make the first image to strech to the left top, the second to the right top, the third to the left bottom and the last one to the right bottom.

Comment: check the updated pen, thats the closes i get :) and i guess Katranci got it for you.